# Load Html With Embedded Resources

Tags: c#, xaml, webview, microsoft-metro

I am using the WebView control in a Windows 8 Metro application. I have an html string which I read off a network stream, that contains embedded images in the markup.

The control works great if the pictures in the html have their source pointing to some website, however the results are not great for images embedded in the markup.

These images do not render, instead some block is rendered which represents a placeholder for the image.

I am using the NavigateToString method, to load the html.

- Is embedded images a limitation of the control or is there a special
  way of loading the html to get the embedded images to appear?
- If this is a limitation of the control, any ideas or suggestions on
  how i can get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research and investigation, i can confirm that:

- You are unable to load html files with linked resources to images,
  css etc. if not embedded within your application itself.

**Workaround:**

- Embed css within html file, instead of a separate file.
- Convert linked images to Base64 and embed within `img` tag.
- Provided the above steps have been followed, you can now store your
  html files in any writable folder that you have access to.
- Next, read the html file contents into a string.
- Finally, to render the html with embedded css and images, pass the
  string from the above step to the `NavigateToString` method of
  the `WebView` control.
- Voila! Your html with all styling and images, should render as
  expected.

**Perhaps not the best solution. However, simple to implement and is workable.**